# How to create an object with callable methods, but which I can also call like a function

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I use d3.js a lot and have been thinking recently about their linearScale function.

It allows you to do this:

```
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([10, 130])
    .range([0, 960]);

x(20); // 80
x(50); // 320
```

As far as I can tell:

- x holds the return value of d3.scaleLinear()
- x is object-like, because we can then call the methods 'range' and 'domain'
- x is also function-like, because we can call it like 'x(20)' and get a return value

I do not need to know anything specific about how d3 implements this, d3 is simply the first example that came to mind of an API that allows me to do this.

I am interested in implementing something similar myself in javascript and would like to know the necessary design pattern in its simplest form.

I have tried looking at the source code for d3, but there is a lot of extra functionality, and it's split over multiple files - which makes it hard for me to find what I'm looking for, especially when I don't know what that is. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: _"x holds the return value of d3.scaleLinear()"_: Nope. `x` is actually whatever `.range` returned.

Comment: @Cerbrus I think .range returns 'this', as you can chain the .domain and .range methods in either order.

Comment: You should take a look at [JavaScript closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

Comment: @Martha: That's probably true, then.

Comment: Functions are objects and can have properties just like any other object.

Comment: @TedHopp I am fairly familiar with closures, and understand how an outer function can return an inner function with access to the outer function's variables, but I cannot then see how methods can be called on it. Do you know if there is a particular word for what I am trying to do so I can research it more effectively?

Comment: Some other relevant concepts are "currying" and "binding".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to note is that in JavaScript functions are just objects which can have properties attached to them, these properties can contain other functions.

Basically `scaleLinear()` returns a function, which in turn is also used as an API object.

The functions which are attached to the API object/function are used to either get or set the internal state created by the encapsulating closure.

The functions which are attached to the API object/function usually return the API instance to allow the chaining of calls.

Hopefully the following example will shed some light on how something like this could be developed.

```js
function Greet() {
  var person = '';
  var message = 'Hello';

  var api = function () {
    console.log(message + ' ' + person);
    return api;
  };

  api.person = function (value) {
    // if nothing is passed into function act as getter
    if (!arguments.length) return person; 
    // otherwise set the value
    person = value;
    // return the api function for more chaining or calling
    return api;
  };

  api.message = function (value) {
    if (!arguments.length) return message; 
    message = value;
    return api;
  };

  return api;
}
    
var greeter = Greet().person('Daniel');

greeter();  // 'Hello Daniel'

greeter.message('Whaddup').person('Martha')(); // 'Whaddup Martha'
```

*I just remembered that Mike Bostock (the creator of d3) wrote a blog post where he covered this pattern in quite a bit of detail:* https://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/

Answer (score 0):

I found [this tutorial](https://www.toptal.com/d3-js/towards-reusable-d3-js-charts) very practical

I have some kind of boilerplate for this approach

```js
function getChart(params) {
    // exposed variables
    var attrs = {
        svgWidth: 400,
        svgHeight: 400,
        marginTop: 5,
        marginBottom: 5,
        marginRight: 5,
        marginLeft: 5,
        data: null
    };


    /*############### IF EXISTS OVERWRITE ATTRIBUTES FROM PASSED PARAM  #######  */

    var attrKeys = Object.keys(attrs);
    attrKeys.forEach(function (key) {
        if (params && params[key]) {
            attrs[key] = params[key];
        }
    })


    //innerFunctions
    var updateData;


    //main chart object
    var chart = function (selection) {
        selection.each(function () {

            //calculated properties
            var calc = {}

            calc.chartLeftMargin = attrs.marginLeft;
            calc.chartTopMargin = attrs.marginTop;

            calc.chartWidth = attrs.svgWidth - attrs.marginRight - calc.chartLeftMargin;
            calc.chartHeight = attrs.svgHeight - attrs.marginBottom - calc.chartTopMargin;

            //drawing
            var svg = d3.select(this)
                .append('svg')
                .attr('width', attrs.svgWidth)
                .attr('height', attrs.svgHeight)
            // .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + attrs.svgWidth + " " + attrs.svgHeight)
            // .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid meet")


            var chart = svg.append('g')
                .attr('width', calc.chartWidth)
                .attr('height', calc.chartHeight)
                .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (calc.chartLeftMargin) + ',' + calc.chartTopMargin + ')')





            // smoothly handle data updating
            updateData = function () {


            }


        });
    }


    //exposed variable funcs
    chart.data = function (value) {
        if (!arguments.length) return attrs.data;
        attrs.data = value;
        if (typeof updateData === 'function') {
            updateData();
        }
        return chart;
    }

    chart.width = function (value) {
        if (!arguments.length) return attrs.svgWidth;
        attrs.svgWidth = value;
        return chart;
    }

    chart.height = function (value) {
        if (!arguments.length) return attrs.svgHeight;
        attrs.svgHeight = value;
        return chart;
    }


    return chart;
}
```

Then you can call chart like that